# Create new Bootstrap row every third array item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of @schools (School.all), and I am displaying these @schools within a Bootstrap row (3 per row). I was wondering how I could make it so that for every third item in @schools, Ruby/Rails would create a new row and then repeat that process. Thanks.

```
<% for 3 in @schools %>
  <div class="row">
    <% @schools.each do |s| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`each_slice`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) is your friend.

```
<% @schools.each_slice(3) do |schools| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% schools.each do |s| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<% @schools.in_groups_of(3) do |schools| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% schools.each do |s| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

For documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of